# Does the old version of apt information file exist on the website?

Tags: apt, package-management, deb

When I execute `apt update`, apt will update the file on the website listed in `/etc/apt/sources.list` to local, for example, http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz, apt update will download this file to local(/var/lib/apt/lists). this file describes the dependencies of the deb package.

Does the old version of this file exist on the website?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The information I want to get is, for example, http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz. apt update will download this information to local(/var/lib/apt/lists). Does the old version of this information exist on the website?

Comment: The tools that create that file are designed to point to only the latest packages.  Also that file can change many times per day (depending on release; the release I'm on now has had 3 dist-upgrades so far today, but I'm on 19.04 and it'll change less on stable or particularly older releases) - it'd waste a lot of space and be a potential pitfall (latest packages are generally safer security-wise).  You'd have to script a scraper yourself to create it.

Comment: Seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): The 'old version' of the Packages file is useless. It's NOT archived, and if it were archived, the older file points to filenames (versions) that are not in the repository anymore. Some were replaced due to published exploits. Whatever problem you actually have, looking for old Packages files seems a dead end. There is a single insecure exception: The base repository for a release (non -security and non -updates) is an old snapshot that is still valid.

Answer (score 1):

The record of each published version of all packages are maintained on Launchpad, along with dependency information. The URLs are of the form:

```
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/<release>/<arch>/<package>/<version>
```

For example:

- Python 3 apt API v1.7.0 for Ubuntu 18.10: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/cosmic/amd64/python-apt/1.7.0
- `libc6-dev` 2.28-0ubuntu1 for Ubuntu 19.04: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/disco/amd64/libc6-dev/2.28-0ubuntu1

You can go to `https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/<release>/+package/<package>` for a list of versions (e.g., https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/bash-doc for Bash documentation in 16.04).

Comment: The information I want to get is, for example, http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz. apt update will download this information to local(/var/lib/apt/lists). Does the old version of this information exist on the website?

Comment: @wzq not as a single file, no. You'll have to look it up individually for each package and version.

Answer (score 0):

If the package has been updated since your release, both the older version and the newer version are maintained on the canonical repositories.  For example, the command `apt list linux-image-4.*generic` yields the results:

```
apt list linux-image-4.*generic
Listing... Done
linux-image-4.18.0-10-generic/cosmic,now 4.18.0-10.11 amd64 [residual-config]
linux-image-4.18.0-10-generic/cosmic 4.18.0-10.11 i386
linux-image-4.18.0-11-generic/cosmic-updates,cosmic-security,now 4.18.0-11.12 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-4.18.0-11-generic/cosmic-updates,cosmic-security 4.18.0-11.12 i386
linux-image-4.18.0-12-generic/cosmic-updates,cosmic-security,now 4.18.0-12.13 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-4.18.0-12-generic/cosmic-updates,cosmic-security 4.18.0-12.13 i386
```

Comment: The information I want to get is, for example, http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz. apt update will download this information to local(/var/lib/apt/lists). Does the old version of this information exist on the website?